# GAE on python + REST, inserting/updating db.ListProperty(users.User)

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, rest, gql

I have a simple **db.Model**, that has one of the fields **db.ListProperty(users.User)**
For the REST server I used http://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server/

However, I can't seem to update this field..
The app is currently password-protected but if anyone wants to take a look, I can make it public.

Basically, I have a form that I post using this jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/rest/' + $this.attr('name') + update,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $this.wsString(),
    });
```

where `$this.wsString()` is applying serializeArray() to the form and after that transforms the result into proper REST format ( + JSON.stringify at the end ).

Here's the metadata for the entity, the "developers" field is the problematic one: http://toxik.appspot.com/Project.xml

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you receiving some data from the client? What do you see in your log?

Comment: @systempuntoout Yes, the form is submitted, and all other fields are populated. I don't know how to send the message for this particular field, that's all

Comment: @systempuntoout I don't think I'm checking the right one since I only see INFO     2011-05-25 12:39:47,302 dev_appserver.py:4151] "POST /rest/Project/agV0b3hpa3ITCxINcHJvamVjdF9tb2RlbBhYDA HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it: **db.ListProperty(users.User)** wants an object that serialized looks like this:

`"developers":{"item":["some1@email.com","some2@email.com"]}`